# Vaadin Passing Date into a gridLayout Label with specific formatting

Tags: formatting, label, vaadin

I am trying to pass a date from a container into a gridLayout label and only want to display the month and day (not the year and time as well).

Please show example if possible. I'm really new.

Comment: What did you have so far?

Comment: Please show some code that represents your efforts so far